# C pthread_cond_wait() doesnt resume program after pthread_cond_signal()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I wanted to test pthread_cond_wait to pause a thread but it just freezes at the printf("thread2"); statement.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
volatile int done = 1;


void *testf(void* no) {
    while (1) {
        printf("thread1\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        printf("thread2\n");
        done = 0;
    }
}




int main() {
    printf("mthread1\n");
    pthread_t pt;
    pthread_create(&pt, NULL, &testf, NULL);
    printf("mthread2\n");
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    printf("mthread3\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    printf("mthread4\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    printf("mthread5\n");

    while (done);
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesnt it resume after cond_signal()? It shoudl just resume.

Comment: Looks lie a deadlock to me.

Comment: The main thread calls pthread_cond_signal before the other thread calls pthread_cond_wait. When it starts waiting, it never finishes waiting because it never gets a signal because the signal already happened.

Comment: You must make sure that the secondary thread is started before calling pthread_cond_signal(). Because when pthread_create() returns, you are not sure that the secondary thread started.

Comment: Signals to condition variables don't queue. If nothing's waiting on one when it's signaled, it's ignored.

Comment: A barrier would have worked here : pthread_barrier_init(), pthread_barrier_wait()

Comment: ..or a semaphore.

Comment: OT: regarding: `void *testf(void* no) {`  since the parameter: `no` is not used, the compiler outputs a warning message.  Suggest the first statement in the body of the function be: `(void)no;` To eliminate that warning message

Answer (score 0):

As the conditional variables are used to set/check variables, I can propose the following enhanced code to test the mechanism. "done" is the variable to check. I added a sleep() in the main thread otherwise in most cases, it has the time to set the "done" variable before the secondary thread has a chance to check it and loop at least once.

Additional notes:

Compared to the code provided in the request : we still can't ensure that the secondary thread is started when pthread_create() returns in the main thread by even if the signal from pthread_cond_signal() is lost, the secondary thread first check the value of the "done" variable protected by the mutex.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
volatile int done = 0;


void *testf(void* no) {

        printf("thread 2 looping\n");

        // Lock the mutex to check the variable
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);

    do {

        if (done) {
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
          printf("thread 2 exiting\n");
          break;
        }

        // The mutex is locked and will be unlocked inside
        // pthread_cond_wait()

        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
        printf("thread 2 signaled\n");

        // The mutex is locked

    } while (1);
}




int main() {

    printf("thread1 starting...\n");
    pthread_t pt;
    pthread_create(&pt, NULL, &testf, NULL);
    printf("thread 1 created thread 2\n");

    printf("thread 1 is doing some dummy work\n");
    sleep(1);

    // Lock the mutex to check/set the variable
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    done = 1;
    printf("thread 1 signaling thread 2\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    printf("thread 1 releases the mutex\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

    printf("thread 1 waiting end of thread 2...\n");
    pthread_join(pt, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I added a note in the answer.